# prove that $\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \,dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx + \int_{b}^{c} f(x) \,dx $

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I've been working on a proof related to the additivity of Riemann integrals and would greatly appreciate insights and feedback for clarity and correctness of the proof. Because i've never seen a text, that tried to prove in this way. Below is the statement and demonstration of my proof.

---

**Definition**
Let $ f(x) $ be a continuous function on an interval $ [a, b] $. Then, if the limit $ \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k $ exists, the function $ f(x) $ is Riemann integrable on $ [a, b] $, and it is defined by:

$$
\lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k = \int_a^b f(x) \,dx
$$

where the definite integral of $ f(x) $ over the interval $ [a, b] $ results in a new function $ g(x) $ calculated on the interval $ [a, b] $, and it can be expressed as:

$$
\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = g(b) - g(a)
$$

By means of the definition.

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx = \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k
$$

where $ c_k $ is in $ [a, b] $, and $ \Delta x_k $ is the width of the corresponding subinterval.

Now, we want to show the relationship.

$$
\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \,dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx + \int_{b}^{c} f(x) \,dx
$$

We can do this by dividing the interval $ [a, c] $ into two subintervals: $ [a, b] $ and $ [b, c] $.

$$
\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \,dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx + \int_{b}^{c} f(x) \,dx
$$

Now, we apply the definition of the definite integral to each term:

$$
\lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_a^c = \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_a^b + \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_b^c
$$

Using the additivity of the limit, we can write:

$$
\lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_a^c = \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_a^b + \lim_{{\| \Delta x_l \| \to 0}} \sum f(c_k) \Delta x_k \Bigg|_b^c
$$

And finally, we rewrite this using the notation of definite integrals:

$$
\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \,dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx + \int_{b}^{c} f(x) \,dx
$$

---

Comment: This is a special case of $\int(f+g)=\int( f)+\int (g)$ , isn't it?

Comment: Your hypothesis are redundant. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then it is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: I am not pleased with this proof, because a subdivision of $[a,b]$ does not necessarily have one of its points equal to $c.$

Answer (score 2):

It seems correct to me; the thesis makes clearly sense if you think of integrals as the area under the curve of a "one dimensional" function (with one variable).
You could also prove that by the definition of integral as it follows:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$$
where $F(x)$ is the anti derivative of $f(x)$; now by summing and subtracting a quantity equal to zero you get:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(c) + F(c) - F(a)$$
but always from definition:
$$F(b) - F(c) + F(c) - F(a) = \int_c^bf(x)dx + \int_a^cf(x)dx$$
putting it all together you get the thesis:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^cf(x)dx + \int_c^bf(x)dx$$

Comment: I see your point; I actually did all of this in high school and I've not yet encountered it in my calculus classes, so it could be as you're saying... I'll look back at my old books and notes, thank you!

Comment: K. Kuratowski (!) does the same in his _Introduction to Calculus_ (1960), Polish edition 1946 .

Comment: No circularity because one doesn't need additivity to prove that $\int_a^{x+h} f - \int_a^x f = f(\xi)\,h$ with $\xi$ between $x$ and $x+h$ .